# Получить всех участников канала Telegram API

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Возможно ли с помощью API Telegram или Telegram Bot API получить список всех участников публичного канала (например, список `user_id`)? Я понимаю, что есть возможность добавить бота и сделать его администратором, но у него так же нет такого метода.

Comment: Нет. Так нельзя получить через `getUpdates`, т.к. участники не контактировали с ботом, и их добавление как-то не записывается в обновления бота. Через telegram API судя по методу можно, но я пока не смогла развернуть приложение и/или правильно прописать запрос. Так что вопрос ещё открыт. Если у кого-то есть набитые шишки, а тем более, правильный путь - пожалуйста напишите сюда ваши рассуждения.

Answer (score 4):

С помощью **Bot API** - **нет**. То, что можно получить :

1. [getChatAdministrators](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatadministrators) - возвращает **список пользователей-администраторов** чата
2. [getChatMembersCount](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmemberscount) - возвращает **количество участников** чата

Однако, тут можно сработать по-другому - при получении обновлений с серверов можно проверять объект [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) на наличие непустого поля **new_chat_members** и записывать этот массив. Само-собой, что список этот со временем будет терять актуальность, так как пользователи добавляются и удаляются. Для актуализации списка пользователей необходимо так же проверять объект [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) на наличие непустого поля **left_chat_member** и удалять из списка пользователя, покинувшего чат.

---

С помощью **Telegram API** - наверное **да**, воспользовавшись методом [messages.getFullChat](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getFullChat) для групп или [channels.getFullChannel](https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.getFullChannel) для каналов, но сам не пробовал.

Comment: С помощью Telegram API  можно, но messages.getFullChat это для групп, для каналов channels.getFullChannel

Comment: @Леха спасибо, дополнил